# Providing updates during a long Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an action that takes a long time. I want to be able to provide updates during the process so the user is not confused as to whether he lost the connection or something. Can I do something like this:

```
class HeavyLiftingController < ApplicationController
  def data_mine
    render_update :js=>"alert('Just starting!')"
    # do some complicated find etc.
    render_update :js=>"alert('Found the records!')"
    # do some processing ...
    render_update :js=>"alert('Done processig')"
    # send @results to view
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to handle the request that way. For each request, you have just one answer.

If your action takes a long time, then maybe it should be performed asynchronously. You could send user e-mails during the process to notify him of the progress.

I suggest that you to take a look on DelayedJob gem:
http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job

It will handle most difficult parts of dealing with assync stuff for you (serializing / deserializing your objects, storage, so on...).

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

No,  you can only issue ONE render within a controller action.  The render does NOTHING until the controller terminates.  When data_mine terminates,  there will be THREE renders,  which will result in an error.

UPDATE:

You'll likely have to set up a JavaScript (jquery) timer in the browser,  then periodically send an AJAX request to the server to determine the current status of your long running task.

For example the long running task could write a log as it progresses,  and the periodic AJAX request would read that log and create some kind of status display,  and return that to the browser for display.

Comment: But there should be some way of doing long tasks and issuing updates to the user? Break it up into smaller actions? But can the actions call one another on the server side?